# Как создать массив в массиве в языке C

Tags: c, массивы, динамические-массивы

Задача: Пользователь должен ввести кол-во массивов,их размер и через что заполнить.
Вопрос: Как занести,заполнить и вывести все массивы? 
Пример: Пользователь вводит кол-во 5,то есть 5 массивов. Теперь вопрос как занести в один массив и потом заполнить?

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>

void InputMassivesKeyboard(int x, int n, int m, int *mass, int **a) {
    int len = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int c;
    printf("Введите кол-во массивов или векторов\n");
    scanf("%d", x);
    for (len = 0; len < x; len++)
    {
        printf("Введите размер матрицы\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        scanf("%d", &m);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)  // цикл по строкам
        {
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++)  // цикл по столбцам
            {
                printf("a[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
                scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
            }
        }
        mass[len] = **a;
        printf("%d", mass[len]);
    }
}

void main() {
    int x;
    int n, m;
    int ent;
    int *mass = 0;
    int **a = 0;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    printf("Введите кол-во массивов или векторов\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    a = (int*)malloc(n*m * sizeof(int));
    mass = (int*)malloc(x * sizeof(int));
    InputMassivesKeyboard(x, n, m, mass, a);
```

Comment: массив массивов это просто двойной указатель. И в таком массиве можно будет хранить указатели на обычные массивы. Это описано в любой книге по с. Что уже пробовали сделать?

Comment: Я создал динамический  двухмерный массив а,который заполняется с клавиатуры,потом создал динамический массив маss. В функции заполнения массива a,я создал счетчик кол-во массивов(for) и при заполнение массива a, происходит алгоритм "mass[len] = **a;",возможно это неправильно,я еще не проверял.

Comment: А этого никто не знает. Лучше обновите вопрос и вставьте туда весь свой код

Comment: я вставил свой код

Comment: как то много раз спрашиваете размеры матриц. И попробуйте все таки аккуратно переписать условие задачи - Вы пишете о массиве массивов, а в коде - массив матриц.

Comment: "Первая программа создает матрицы или векторы указанного размера. Количество матриц и векторов, их размер и способ задания (с клавиатуры или случайным образом) задаются с клавиатуры.
Вторая программа выполняет векторные, матрично-векторные и матричные операции с указываемыми данными (данные первой программы). Организовать вывод результатов." Да,мне нужен массив массивов,но я не знаю как написать этот код,чтоб в массив входили другие массивы,после чего можно было бы вывести через этот массив таблицы каждого массива

Comment: Так сущность вида `x[m][n]` это и есть массив массивов (m массивов, каждый из которых размера n)